# How to embed superset dashboard into your app

Tags: apache-superset

Here I am trying to embed a superset dashborad into my local .net core web app using [@superset-ui/embedded-sdk,](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@superset-ui/embedded-sdk)
I am using the docker method to deploy superset server in my local machine and was able to create and published dashboard in my superset server
but when I embed that dashboard into my app it end up with a blank page and there was a console error, Any help?

Here is my code

```
<div><iframe id="super"></iframe></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@@superset-ui/embedded-sdk"></script>
<script>
    supersetEmbeddedSdk.embedDashboard({
        id: "***************", 
        supersetDomain: "http://localhost:8088/",
        mountPoint: document.getElementById("super"), 
        fetchGuestToken: () => getToken(),
        dashboardUiConfig: { hideTitle: true }, 
    });
async function getToken() {
        const { data: token } = await axios.post(
            'http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/login',
            {
                username: '***',
                password: '***',
                provider: 'db',
                refresh: false,
            }
        );
        console.log('access token here');
        console.log(token.access_token);            
        try {
            var data = await axios.post(
                'http://localhost:8088/api/v1/security/guest_token/',
                {
                    user: {
                        username: '***',
                        first_name: '***',
                        last_name: '***',
                    },
                    rls: [],
                    resources: [
                        {
                            type: 'dashboard',
                            id: '************',
                        },
                    ],
                },
                {
                    headers: {                           
                        Authorization: `Bearer ${token.access_token}`,
                    },
                },
            );
            console.log('guest token here');
            console.log(data);
            return data.data.token;
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e.message);
            console.error(e);
            return e;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Console error:
[image]

Comment: Note I am still trying to get superset to display on mine, but to get past the 403 error I had to have my fetchGuestToken return a promise that resolved to the token value itself, and not a a struct of {token: "tokeValue"}

Comment: Yes I updated that promise to the token value itself, But still getting `403 error` . any clue regarding this?